# Не работает интернет Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

На пк установлена ос: Windows 10 Home.
Проблема простая - не работает интернет. Wifi модуля нет. Подключен через кабель Ethernet.

В параметрах сети сказано, что все в порядке и доступ к интернету есть, однако в браузере(chrome/edge) ни один сайт не загружается. Причем nslookup и ping дают положительный результат в консоли. Пробовал менять dns, но не помогло. Спасал только VPN (с ним все работало, а значит проблема не в аппаратной составляющей), но вечно им пользоваться я не хотел.

Дело дошло до переустановки Windows, но, как оказалось, даже система не имеет доступа в интернет, хотя, чудом, mos.ru он загрузил, что вызвало еще большее недоумение(получается, что интернет все-таки работает?). Драйверы видеокарты и т.д. не загружаются. В итоге сижу с «мертвой коробкой». Да есть вариант все установить вручную, но хочется разобраться, в чем проблема.

Примечание: с другими устройствами в сети все в порядке, и через тот же кабель ethernet от того же порта все работает.

UPD: Периодически в параметрах сети пишет: «подключение к Интернету отсутсвует» , затем снова меняет статус на «Подключено»

Заранее огромное спасибо!
[image: окно браузера]

[image: ping]

[image: nslookup]

Comment: Отключите прокси в настройках windows.

Comment: Прокси сервер уже был отключен.

Comment: если пинг (то есть по ip) и nslookup (то есть, dns) работает, то  с большой вероятностью проблема действительно в браузере. Я видел очень похожее, когда один чудный вируснячек подымал свой прокси и через себя все проксировал. Но он не справлялся с нагрузкой...

Comment: какой то подозрительный адрес днс сервера. Если это домашняя сеть, то в 99 процентов случаев оно совпадает с роутером, который обычно имеет адрес с .1 в конце. Посмотрите днс сервер на других, нормальный компах и сравните.

Comment: У меня было несколько раз при установке чистой windows 10, в параметрах включался флажок прокси, даже если отключить, он всё равно сам включался. ping проходит, но в браузере не работает.